# Init to zero a static 2D array at its declaration

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I have to declare an initialize a private 2D array this way, because I'm going to use it on a C++ function:

```
@implementation MyClass

int myArray[NSFirstDim][NSSecondDim] = 0; <-- Error here

...

- (id)init
{
...
}

...
@end
```

But I can't initialize to 0 this way because I get the following message:

```
Array initializer must be an initializer list
```

**How can I initialize all values to zero?**

Or I can use a 2D dynamic array...

Comment: use std::vector instead, or even better - std::map. Why to use C-based arrays?

Comment: @art-divin: Both have a (possibly significant) runtime cost, so why should you use either in preference to a simple fixed-size array? In particular, `map` is entirely unsuitable, except perhaps to reduce the storage used by a sparse array.

Comment: @MikeSeymour there are lots of pros and cons in this kind of decisions, but for simpler approach it would be better to use std or objc objects for implementation. We can see from this line "because I'm going to use it on a C++ function" in the question that author just wants to use array in C++ method, he hasn't specified that he is trying to reach maximum performance (which is also under the question mark).

Comment: @art-divin: There are no cons to using an array here (at least versus C++ containers; I don't know enough about Objective-C to comment about those) - it's more convenient to declare and initialise, just as convenient to access, and much more efficient. If you're going to claim otherwise, then you should back up that claim, not just say that using a class is somehow a "simpler approach".

Comment: @MikeSeymour I am sorry I forgot to specify that in programming style and insurance of future code support it is a better approach

Comment: @art-divin: That makes no sense at all, I'm afraid; and I can't be bothered to argue any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
int myArray[NSFirstDim][NSSecondDim] = {0};
```

this is a powerful behavior from C, where you **add values from start** and rest (others) are initialized to 0.

In this sample code,

```
int arr[4][3]={1,2,3};

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        NSLog(@"%d",arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

> Output: 1,2,3,0,0,0,....

Answer (score 6):

```
int myArray[NSFirstDim][NSSecondDim] = {0};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int myArray[NSFirstDim][NSSecondDim] = {0};
```

This statement intializes all elements of 2D array to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Initialising arrays in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770081/initialising-arrays-in-c), I found it quite usefull.

This may also work:
    int myArray[NSFirstDim][NSSecondDim] = {};

Answer (score -2):

How about this int myArray[2][1]  = { {0},{0}};

Comment: i wonder whats the benefit of this `int array[2][1]`, two rows each having one column. i.e. 2 values only.

Comment: just another way on initialization :).

Comment: here you go with yet another way `int array[2][1][1][1][1][1][1]..[1]` :p